# Replace all 0's with 5's in a given number using sprintf and sscanf

Tags: c++, c, printf, scanf

I am trying to replace all the 0's present in a given integer with 5's.

To do that i am using sprintf to convert integer to string and do the operations on the string and finally convert back the string into an integer

Below is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

    int num=0, i=0;
    char str[10];

    printf("Enter the number: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);

    sprintf(str,"%d",num);
    printf("string str:%s",str);
    while(str[i]!='\0')
    {
        if(str[i]==0)
            str[i]=5;
        i++;
    }

    sscanf(str,"%d",&num);

    printf("\nBefore replacement: %s", str);
    printf("\nAfter replacement: %d", num);

}
```

I am getting wrong output

Could someone identify and correct what is wrong here. Thanks :)

Comment: `scanf("%d",num);` should have `&num` and your compiler should be screaming warnings at you! Further `char str[10];` is not sufficient to hold the full range of `int`, you would need `char str[11];` minimum.

Comment: Thanks David :) edited the code.
Getting wrong outputs now

Comment: `if(str[i]==0)` should be with `'0'`. The same for `str[i]=5`

Comment: I encourage you to do additional changes in your code, see my answer

Comment: @MohamedSharief you also know you can do it without a call to `sprintf` or `sscanf` simply by using `% * /`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`scanf("%d", num);` should be `scanf("%d", &num);`.

Also, this here

```
if (str[i] == 0)
    str[i] = 5;
```

should be

```
if (str[i] == '0')
    str[i] = '5';
```

Because `0` is just the same as `'\0'`, but you want to replace the character representing `0`.

Also, in your output, you got before and after mixed up.

Answer (score 3):

```
    if(str[i]==0)
        str[i]=5;
```

must be

```
    if(str[i]=='0')
        str[i]='5';
```

---

I also encourage you to check the initial *scanf* returns 1 to know if the user enter or not a valid input

and in

```
printf("\nBefore replacement: %s", str);
printf("\nAfter replacement: %d", num);
```

to produce the \n at the end to have

```
printf("Before replacement: %s\n", str);
printf("After replacement: %d\n", num);
```

but note you write the string *after* the replacements rather than *before*, you have to move the case *before* before the *while* or to just remove it because you already written the string before the replacements

Example :

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

    int num=0, i=0;
    char str[10];

    printf("Enter the number: ");
    if (scanf("%d",&num) != 1)
      puts("invalid input");
    else {
      sprintf(str,"%d",num);
      printf("string str:%s\n",str);
      while(str[i]!='\0')
      {
        if(str[i]=='0')
          str[i]='5';
        i++;
      }

      sscanf(str,"%d",&num);

      printf("After replacement: %d\n", num);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Compilation and executions :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wextra c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Enter the number: aze
invalid input
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Enter the number: 10204
string str:10204
After replacement: 15254
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void ReplaceZeroWithFive()
{
    int[] arr = { 10000, 100005, 8978005, 90000007 };

    foreach (var item in arr)
    {
        int output = GetModifiedNumber(item);
        Console.WriteLine($"no :{item} , updatedwith :{output}");
    }
}

private static int GetModifiedNumber(int number)
{
    if (number == 0) return 5;
    int result = 0, dec = 1;
    while (number > 0)
    {
        int rem = number % 10 == 0 ? 5 : number % 10;
        result += rem * dec;
        number /= 10;
        dec *= 10;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Console.WriteLine() is from .Net API, not a native C++ or STD function.

Comment: thanks for pointing out this, i just gave the basic algo ......which might not inline with with title.......

Comment: You're welcome, I just noticed that the question didn't contain a tag related to .Net, so pure C++ answers were anticipated.